# Search engine comparison tool. Google and Bing

Tags: web, search-engine, bing

I am trying to build a search engine comparison tool between bing and google that will analyze which of the top n results are matching. Since I don't have much web-development experience, (most of my experience lies in Windows Application development and lower level stuff.) I was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction. I'm guessing that one way of doing this would be to download the search results and somehow find all of the links which are results and then comparing them.

What language can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a language of your choice and build upon APIs. Bing already has [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251072.aspx)
Although Google doesn't have a direct search API (at least none that I know of), if you are a student planning to do some research, you can sign up for their [university program](http://research.google.com/university/search/) and they'll expose you an API. Trying to download the page and parsing it would be difficult, since Google uses some security measures to avoid direct crawls.

Comment: thanks I will try those things you mentioned, and thanks for pointing me in a direction